# Why does Visual Studio C++ take so long to compile

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use a pretty decent 3.4Ghz 4 core intel i5 cpu, and a Radeon Rx 560 Gpu, but for some reason it still takes at least 10-20 seconds to compile my code. Is there a way to speed it up? Or is this just how c++ works?

Comment: Without more details, it's impossible to help you. What code are you compiling? How large is the codebase? What are the dependencies? Is it TMP heavy? Does the code try to include binary resources such as outputs of `xxd` and so many open questions

Comment: The GPU doesn't have anything to do with the compile performance, but your HDD or SSD and memory size will make a big difference since compiling is disk I/O bound operation. Likely the creation of the Precompiled Header (PCH) is dominating your compile times, or the link time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, it doesn't matter what the specifications of your computer are. The size of some large scale Windows C++ projects can just take a lot longer because there is simply a lot more code, more functions to compile & link and or analyze. There are some things you can do to speed up the process by, using PCH (Pre-compiled Headers) or if your compiling in debug you can use the /debug:fastlink linker switch etc.

You can read more about ways to make MSVC faster here: [Microsoft Devblogs Recommendations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/recommendations-to-speed-c-builds-in-visual-studio/)